# .net core with elasticsearch in docker blocked by connection limit

Tags: .net, docker, elasticsearch, nest, kestrel

i have asp.net core app 2.2. using Elasticsearch 7.5.0
When I run app in a Windows environment, there are no problems. (elasticsearch always in docker).
But when I launch the application in the docker environment, the application stops responding when it is loaded (30rps +). A request to the elastic waits for a connection and dies by timeout. If set Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 8-32 (kestrel options), the api successfully sends requests to the elastic but most of the requests are deleted, which is unacceptable.

ElasticClient:

```
            var _connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(baseElasticConfig.Uri))
                 .BasicAuthentication(baseElasticConfig.Login, baseElasticConfig.Password)
                 .DefaultIndex(baseElasticConfig.IndexDecider);
            var client = new ElasticClient(_connectionSettings);
            builder.Register(x => client).As<IElasticClient>().SingleInstance();
```

With requests to postgres this problem is not. I think nest cannot open http connection.

Comment: What is the ideal behaviour you would like to see that it's not doing right now?

Comment: Behavior as on windows in which there are no restrictions on connections

Comment: Can you add more detail about the docker environment for the app?

Comment: I wonder if the environment is using `HttpClient` that uses `System.Net.Http.CurlHandler`. See `ConnectionLimit`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html

Comment: Sorry, there were synchronous calls and there was a threadpool starvation